# How can we install MongoDB 3.4 version on Ubuntu 18.04, Is Ubuntu 18.04 support MongoDB 3.4

Tags: mongodb

we having MongoDB setup on Ubuntu 14.04 now Ubuntu 14.o4 support will going to end at 2018.we are planning to move our setup on 18.04. But there are no details available for Ubuntu 18.04 and our MongoDB running on 3.4 version. Is Ubuntu 18.04 support 3.4 version of MongoDB? .Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to upgrade to 3.6, using docker is a good way.

For example,

```
docker run -it --rm -v /YOUR/LOCAL/MONGODB/DATA:/data/db -w /YOUR/LOCAL/MONGODB/DATA -p 27017:27017 library/mongo:3.4
```

Once you run 3.4 on your database, you can upgrade to 3.6 smoothly.

Answer (score -2):

First, update the packages list to have the most recent version of the repository listings:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Now install the MongoDB package itself:

```
$ sudo apt install -y mongodb
```

This command installs several packages containing the latest stable version of MongoDB, along with helpful management tools for the MongoDB server. The database server is automatically started after installation.

Verfiy if the server is running fine :

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

The output should be :

```
Output
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-05-26 07:48:04 UTC; 2min 17s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Main PID: 2312 (mongod)
    Tasks: 23 (limit: 1153)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─2312 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

According to **systemd**, the MongoDB server is up and running.

Verify this further by actually connecting to the database server and executing a diagnostic command:

```
$ mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'
```

Desired output would be:

```
Output
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
{
        "authInfo" : {
                "authenticatedUsers" : [ ],
                "authenticatedUserRoles" : [ ]
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

If you intend to use the MongoDB server only locally with applications running on the same server, this is the recommended and secure setting. However, if you would like to be able to connect to your MongoDB server from the internet, you have to allow the incoming connections in ufw.

To allow access to MongoDB on its default port 27017 from everywhere, you could use sudo ufw allow 27017. However, enabling internet access to MongoDB server on a default installation gives anyone unrestricted access to the database server and its data.

```
$ sudo ufw allow from your_other_server_ip/32 to any port 27017
```

You can verify the firewall status :

```
$ sudo ufw status
```

Output:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Even though the port is open, MongoDB is currently only listening on the local address 127.0.0.1. To allow remote connections, add your server's publicly-routable IP address to the mongod.conf file.

Open the MongoDB configuration file

```
$ sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Add your server's IP address to the bindIP value:

```
...
logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,your_server_ip
#port = 27017

...
```

Be sure to place a comma between the existing IP address and the one you added.

Save the file, exit the editor, and restart MongoDB:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mongodb
```

Check [this](https://robomongo.org/) for a GUI.

You'll have your MongoDB server running up in no time.

Comment: OP's specifically asking for mongodb 3.4!