# How to install Mongo 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

So the things I have tried are:

1)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

2)

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse
```

3)

```
sudo apt-get update
```

4)

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.10 mongodb-org-server=3.4.10 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.10 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.10 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.10
```

But I got this error:

```
E: Version '3.4.10' for 'mongodb-org' was not found
E: Version '3.4.10' for 'mongodb-org-server' was not found
E: Version '3.4.10' for 'mongodb-org-shell' was not found
E: Version '3.4.10' for 'mongodb-org-mongos' was not found
E: Version '3.4.10' for 'mongodb-org-tools' was not found
```

I have read the other [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109699/how-can-we-install-mongodb-3-4-version-on-ubuntu-18-04-is-ubuntu-18-04-support) about this, but it did not work for me and I don't want to use a docker image.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ok so the things to do to install this version are

### Step 1

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

### Step 2

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

### Step 3

```
sudo apt update
```

### Step 4

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.17 mongodb-org-server=3.4.17 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.17 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.17 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.17
```

here is the really helpful source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089312/install-and-use-mongodb-3-4-17-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Step 1 to add repo key is now `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -`. The current version for step 4 is `3.4.24`.